# How to set new value into existing object in ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Im still quite new into Java and I'm trying to set new value to specific field into existing object in arraylist.
I've got one class:

```
public class Client 
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

//skip setters and getters
```

I added objects to arraylist using

```
listOfClients.add
```

and now I'd like to update only lastName in one of existing objects. To pick one of all objects I'm using index of Arraylist but still have no idea how can I update only this one spcific value. So far i've tried

`listOfClients.set`

but it didn't go well. 
Could anyone tell me if there is any way to update only one, specific field in my object?

Comment: Get the object from that list (using List.get() for example), and modify it (using its setter)

Comment: ArrayList is a sequential list. So, insertion and retrieval order is the same. You can get the element from the list by .get() and modify it by setting firstName or lastName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use the list's get method.**

> The get method returns the element at the specified position in this
>   list.

Use it as follows:

```
listOfClients.get(clientIndex).setFirstName(newFirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the index, you can try  `listOfClients.get(index).setLastName("value")`.

`listOfClients.get(index)` gets you the object. Then you can set any value  with it's setter method.

Answer (score 0):

find the index of the value and set it using:  list.set( index_of_the value_to change, "value_to_update" );

**Here is the example for your question i am updating the cow value here:**

ArrayList nums = new ArrayList<>();

```
    nums.add("Rat");
    nums.add("cow");
    nums.add("rabbit");
    System.out.println(nums);

    nums.set(1, "updated");
    System.out.println(nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Client> clientList=new ArrayList<Client>();

Client c1=new Client();
c1.setFirstName("First");
c1.setLastName("FirstLast");

clientList.add(c1);
System.out.println("First: "+clientList.get(0).getFirstName() +"-"+         clientList.get(0).getLastName());
//Modify by setter

clientList.get(0).setLastName("ModifyLast");

System.out.println("After"+clientList.get(0).getFirstName() +"-"+ clientList.get(0).getLastName());

}

public static class Client{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

}
```